# Connecting and using two external monitorson MacBook Pro early 2015

Tags: thunderbolt, hdmi, displayport

I have been using an LG 5K monitor hooked up to my MacBook Pro via one Thunderbolt 2 on one female connection for quite a while.  I tried to hook up an AOC E2752S via HDMI to Thunderbolt 2 to the second female connection but it kick out the LG.  Had to disconnect to get the LG back working after some time.  Is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Since your Mac doesn’t support one 5k display at full resolution - are you asking us to recommend lower resolution displays or upgrade to a more powerful mac? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210205

Comment: Graphics card cannot handle combined resolution of the displays.

Comment: Thanks for both of you comments.I am not looking to upgrade my mac.

Comment: Is there a solution to the graphics card issue?